# Side panel with components loading dynamically based on context

Tags: reactjs, react-component

With react: how can I render a side panel component with different components depending on the type of action. To give a concrete example:

On the main page, I have a table with some rows. Every row may be of a different "type" (Row 1 may be of type A, Row 2 may be of type B.

When I click on a row that's type A, I would like to render components related to the type A row, and different components for type B row.

You can almost define the panel like a "widget" area, where I can load different components based on different context, or action I perform outside of that area.

Below is what I am trying to do.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by changing the data stored on state of the selected row type.

For example:

```js
state = {
  currently_selected_type : ""
}
```

In your render function, we can have something like this:

```js
render(){
  let SidePanelComponent = null;
  if(this.state.currently_selected_type === "A"){
    SidePanelComponent = (<div>A</div>);
  }
  else if(this.state.currently_selected_type === "B"){
    SidePanelComponent = (<div>B</div>);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Table
        onClick={
          // this type will be passed from the inside Table when rows are clicked based on the row type
          (type) => this.setState({currently_selected_type : type})
        }
       />
      {SidePanelComponent}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Inside the `Table` component you will be rendering the different types of rows, so based on what row is click just send the type to the passed `onClick` function.

The `Table` render function can be as follows, for example:

```js
render(){
  return (
  ...
   <tr onClick={this.props.onClick("A")}>Row Type A</tr>
   <tr onClick={this.props.onClick("B")}>Row Type B</tr>
  ...
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out:

I created a `context` and a `provider`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PanelContext from './panelContext'

const PanelProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [content, setContent] = useState(undefined);

    return (
        <PanelContext.Provider
            value={{
                content: content,
                setContent: setContent
            }}>
            {children}
        </PanelContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default PanelProvider;
```

Then I created a `usePanel` hook:

```
import PanelContext from "../contexts/panel/panelContext";

const usePanel = () => {
    const { content, setContent } = useContext(PanelContext)
    return {content, setContent};
}

export default usePanel;
```

Then in my Table Row component, I use it:

```
const { setContent } = usePanel();

...
...

const testCallback = (e) => console.log(e.target.value)

...
...

setContent(<Input value="wow!!!!" onChange={testCallback} />)
```

And finally, on the actual panel component itself:

```
import { usePanel } from "../../../hooks"

export default ({ }) => {

    const { content } = usePanel();
    
    return (
        <aside className="contextualizer" id="contextualizer">
            <PerfectScrollbar>
                <div className="customizer-body">
                    {content}
                </div>
            </PerfectScrollbar>
        </aside >
    );
}
```

Works perfectly.